How to add security handler
I have setup a simple Jetty 12 server to render dynamic content using Handler.Abstract.
PathMappingsHandler pathMappingsHandler = new PathMappingsHandler();
pathMappingsHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/"), new IndexHandler());
pathMappingsHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/users"), new UsersHandler());

Handler.Sequence handlers = new Handler.Sequence();
handlers.addHandler(pathMappingsHandler);
handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

server.setHandler(handlers);

public class UsersHandler extends Handler.Abstract {
    private static final Configuration cfg = FreeMarkerUtil.getFreeMarkerCfgInstance();

    @Override
    public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback) throws Exception {
        Template fmtemplate = cfg.getTemplate("users.html");
        Map<String, Object> datamap = new HashMap<>();
        List<AppUser> users = getData();
        datamap.put("users", users);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        fmtemplate.process(datamap, writer);
        String msg = writer.toString();

        response.setStatus(200);
        response.getHeaders().put(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        Content.Sink.write(response, true, msg, callback);
        return true;
    }
}

The code is working fine.
How do I add a security handler to pathMappingsHandler, so that only authenticated users get the response from UsersHandler?
The Jetty 12 documentation has this comment

Securing HTTP Server Applications
TODO

The jetty-examples repository in Git does not have an example either.

I figured that out. And here are the working code snippets.
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = App.newServer();
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

private static Server newServer() {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setDefaultHandler(new DefaultHandler(false, false));

    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpConfig.setFormEncodedMethods("POST");
    httpConfig.setRelativeRedirectAllowed(true);

    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    ContextHandler rootContextHandler = new ContextHandler(new IndexHandler(), "/app");
    server.setHandler(rootContextHandler);

    SecurityHandler.PathMapped securityHandler = new SecurityHandler.PathMapped();
    securityHandler.setAuthenticator(getAuthenticator());
    securityHandler.setLoginService(getLoginService());
    securityHandler.put(PathSpec.from("/"), Constraint.ALLOWED);
    securityHandler.put(PathSpec.from("/index"), Constraint.ALLOWED);
    
    /** Any request to /app/auth/* should be authenticated. */
    securityHandler.put(PathSpec.from("/auth/*"), Constraint.ANY_USER);

    SessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
    /** Expire the User Session after 10 mins of Idle-Time */
    sessionHandler.setMaxInactiveInterval(600);
    PathMappingsHandler pathMappingsHandler = new PathMappingsHandler();
    pathMappingsHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/"), new IndexHandler());
    pathMappingsHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/index"), new IndexHandler());
    pathMappingsHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/login"), new LoginHandler());  
    pathMappingsHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/auth/users"), new UsersHandler());

    /** Nest the Handlers */
    rootContextHandler.setHandler(sessionHandler);
    sessionHandler.setHandler(securityHandler);
    securityHandler.setHandler(pathMappingsHandler);

    return server;
}

private static Authenticator getAuthenticator() {
    FormAuthenticator formAuthenticator = new FormAuthenticator("/login", "/error", true);
    formAuthenticator.setAlwaysSaveUri(true);
    return formAuthenticator;
}

private static LoginService getLoginService() {
    HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService("HashAuth");
    loginService.setUserStore(getUserStore());
    return loginService;
}

private static UserStore getUserStore() {
    UserStore userStore = new UserStore();
    userStore.addUser("user1", new Password("user1"), new String[] { "user" });
    userStore.addUser("user2", new Password("user2"), new String[] { "admin" });
    userStore.addUser("user3", new Password("user3"), new String[] { "user", "admin" });
    return userStore;
}

public class LoginHandler extends Handler.Abstract {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersHandler.class);
    private static final Configuration cfg = FreeMarkerUtil.getFreeMarkerCfgInstance();

    @Override
    public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Handling Login");
        Template fmtemplate = cfg.getTemplate("login.html");

        Map<String, Object> datamap = new HashMap<>();
        String msg = "Login With Your Credentials";
        datamap.put("msg", msg);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        fmtemplate.process(datamap, writer);
        String outmsg = writer.toString();

        response.setStatus(200);
        response.getHeaders().put(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        Content.Sink.write(response, true, outmsg, callback);
        return true;
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <form method="post" action="/app/j_security_check">
      <p>${msg}</p>
      <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" size="18" minlength="4" maxlength="18"
        placeholder="Your Username" /> <br />
      <br />
      <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" size="18" maxlength="18" minlength="4"
        placeholder="Your Password" /><br /> <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>

</html>

